# Launch asp.net web application in browser when user logon into system

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have created one web application in asp.net and it's purpose is ask basic questions to company employee when they login into their system.

Basic requirement is like they don't want to open browser and enter website URL to attend this questions. We have to force them to attend this questions before do any regular work and when they login into their system.

Is it possible to achieve this or is there any other way if it's possible into windows base application?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to achieve it. Now I have completely answered your question.

Comment: You can't use a web application without a browser of some kind. You will either need to launch the browser pointing to the web application, or write a desktop application using the web browser control.

Comment: You could create a Windows Forms application and a web service layer for it to talk to, and use group policy to force the app to start when they login. This explains the latter part - http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/208799-programs-documents-run-user-logon.html

Comment: If the workstations are on an Active Directory, a GPO can be configured to open the browser window within a Logon script.  The logon scripts executes before the shell is launched, fulfilling the requirement to "attend to questions before any regular work when they login".

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of options:

1) You can create a simpest [Node Web Kit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) app.
To create the simplest one - just create file package.json

```
{
  "name": "your-app-name",
  "main": "http://your-asp-net-app.com/"
}
```

then zip it and rename zip archive to app.nw.

To launch it you should call "nw app.nw".
Or you can create a single executible by performing

```
copy /b nw.exe+app.nw app.exe
```

[See details here](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps)

2) Or create a desktop WinForms app using [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp)

First option is a cross platform solution. And you can rely on browser capabilities - it will always be chromium.

As [drf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/859891/drf) mentioned, you can use Active Directory GPO to configure launching your app at logon

If you really need to launch only this app until user finish his/her work with your app, you can use registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon Shell" to specify your app path instead of explorer.exe. When the work is done, you can launch explorer.exe from your app programmatically. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/75420/stop-explorer-exe-running-in-windows-xp) for more info